# Deserialize JSON with dot in property name

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to deserialize JSON with dots in the property names into a key-value format. I am using the inbuilt ASP.NET MVC model binding. It seems to be interpreting the dots as a object notation instead of just a key-value object. Is there any way to make it deserialize correctly as a key value ignoring the dots? This is important as the data will need to be output again in this format.

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveProgress(int id, ProgressVM data)
{
    // ProgressVM Data property has an item with key "prop" and a null value, nothing else
}
```

View model

```
public class ProgressVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

JSON Example

```
{
    "ID": 123,
    "Data": {
        "prop.0.name": "value",
        "prop.0.id": "value",
        "prop.1.name": "value",
        "prop.2.name": "value",
        "prop.3.name": "value"
    }
}
```

Comment: So where is it giving you the problem? Sending the data ckuent-server or vice versa?

Comment: Sending the data from client to server, deserializing in the action method.

Comment: What if instead of dots you used commas, hyphens, or semi-colons?

Comment: I have thought of replacing the dots, however I was hoping there was a nicer solution to allow it to just work, may have to do this

Comment: Can you please paste the code of the `SaveProgress` action invocation? I suppose you call this action through AJAX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, when passing parameters in a `POST` action, you pass only one parameter and not multiple. So, try to create a model where the Id and the ProgressVM model will be included.

Now, for the issue with the deserialization. Something seems wrong with the [JsonValueProviderFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonvalueproviderfactory.aspx) class, as it does not bind the nested `Dictionary<string, string>` from `ProgressVM` model. I know, because I tried to create a `ModelBinder` for this model, but it fails on the `DictionaryValueProvider`, not binding the `Data` property. Unfortunately, I haven't searched why this is happening, is it a bug on `JsonValueProviderFactory`? I do not know, so I moved quickly to another workaround.

Why don't you try to give the JSON string to the controller instead of the model, and then in the body of the controller deserialize the input?
Look at the example below:

**JavaScript code, using jQuery AJAX to post data**

```
var data = {
    "ID": 123,
    "Data": {
        "prop.0.name": "value",
        "prop.0.id": "value",
        "prop.1.name": "value",
        "prop.2.name": "value",
        "prop.3.name": "value"
    }
}; 

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveProgress", "Home")',
    data: { "data": JSON.stringify(data) },
    method: "POST"
});
```

**ASP.NET MVC Controller action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveProgress(string data)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProgressVM>(data);
    // Rest of code here
}
```

Is this answering your question?

Comment: Thanks for testing all that, seems you are getting similar results to me. Passing the JSON in as a string and deserializing in the action definitely works a lot better.

Comment: What if the response we receive has a dot in property name?

Answer (score 15):

I came here looking for a way to deserialize a json string into a model, and while the question here is solved though the MVC framework, it did not solve my issue.

Given a json string of

```
{
   "Property.Something": "The value"
}
```

I found that using the [JsonProperty] attribute I could deserialize the string into my model like this:

```
public class JsonModel
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Property.Something")]
   public string PropertySomething {get; set;}
}
```