# How to parse JSON data having dot(.) operator?

Tags: c#, class

I have a JSON response like below:

```
{
    "sitePropertiesMap": 
    {
        "site.web.url.protocol": 
        {
            "sitePropertyId": 2497,
            "siteId": 66,
            "key": "site.web.url.protocol",
            "value": "https",
            "type": null,
            "globalAdminOnly": "disabled",
            "hideDefaultValue": "disabled"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access the "sitePropertyId" value from this? I tried to create a modal class like below:

```
public class sitePropertiesMap
{
    public class site.web.url.protocol
    {
         public string sitePropertyId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But getting an error because the class name having a dot operator(.)

Error Screenshot:

[image]

In this case, how can I parse the JSON value?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is a recently added option in visual studio to paste JSON as classes

Comment: @bradbury9 I have used http://json2csharp.com/ for converting JSON to model class, but no luck.

Comment: Can you rephrase your title? Xamarin.Forms does not relate to the underlying question. Also the dot-operator is not related to JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON with dot in property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689872/deserialize-json-with-dot-in-property-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `JsonProperty` attribute of `JSON.NET`

```
public class Rootobject
        {
            public Sitepropertiesmap sitePropertiesMap { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sitepropertiesmap
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "site.web.url.protocol")]

            public SiteWebUrlProtocol siteweburlprotocol { get; set; }
        }

        public class SiteWebUrlProtocol
        {
            public int sitePropertyId { get; set; }
            public int siteId { get; set; }
            public string key { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
            public object type { get; set; }
            public string globalAdminOnly { get; set; }
            public string hideDefaultValue { get; set; }
        }
```

And then deserialize like this:

`var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);`

You need to use `using Newtonsoft.Json;` to use this.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use [Newtonsoft's PropertyName](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute and remove the dots inside the property's name of your model class.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/uFnHEK

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "{\"sitePropertiesMap\": { \"site.web.url.protocol\": { \"sitePropertyId\": 2497, \"siteId\": 66, \"key\": \"site.web.url.protocol\", \"value\": \"https\", \"type\": null, \"globalAdminOnly\": \"disabled\", \"hideDefaultValue\": \"disabled\" } } }";

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.sitePropertiesMap.SiteWebUrlProtocol.sitePropertyId); 
    }
}

public class SiteWebUrlProtocol
{
    public int sitePropertyId { get; set; }
    public int siteId { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public object type { get; set; }
    public string globalAdminOnly { get; set; }
    public string hideDefaultValue { get; set; }
}

public class SitePropertiesMap
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "site.web.url.protocol")]
    public SiteWebUrlProtocol SiteWebUrlProtocol { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public SitePropertiesMap sitePropertiesMap { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string,SiteProperties> SitePropertiesMap { get; set; }
}

public class SiteProperties
{
    public int SitePropertyId { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string GlobalAdminOnly { get; set; }
    public string HideDefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

and access the value like

```
obj.SitePropertiesMap["site.web.url.protocol"].SitePropertyId
```

[.net fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sHRiZq)